# Why do the ViewControllers in UIPageViewControllers not adjust properly using autolayout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

This is what is occurring in gif form:

http://makeagif.com/SAcOBQ (Sorry about quality)

Notice the UILabel at the top takes a moment to move down into its proper location.

No constraints that are ambiguous, I am very confused. Using XCode 6 GM.

The UIImage is adjusting fine.

Another ViewController that a segue leads to has a UILabel at the same position/same constraints and has no issue. That particular VC is not embedded in a pageviewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with the topLayoutGuide. The height of the statusbar is ignored when the view's frame is offscreen (not {0,0}) when adding to the view hierarchy. I think it's a bug in Xcode 6.

I solved this with a workarround like this:

```
CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
CGRect frameSave = frame;
frame.origin.x = 0;
frame.origin.y = 0;
self.view.frame = frame;
[theContainingView addSubview:self.view];
self.view.frame = frameSave;
```

I don't know if it's possible to use this in UIPageViewController. But when You find a way it will workaround the bug.

Comment: The view being the UILabel in this case? Thx for feedback

Comment: I did this with the containing view. The topLayoutGuide doesn't respect the statusBar when the view ist not at {0,0} in iOS 8.